# Upgraded Fedora 24, Gradle status text does not show

Tags: java, gradle, fedora

Prior to upgrading to Fedora 24, I would see output from Gradle like the following:

```
> Loading
> Configuring project 0/20
> Executing test 39 of 4049, 12 skipped.
```

I've read that users often set `TERM=dumb` in order to *disable* this output; however, my `TERM` environment variable is set to `xterm-256color`.

Could someone tell me what I need to set or change under Fedora 24 (which seemed to exist in Fedora 23) to allow me to get this Gradle output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Gradle is wanting to use ncurses5 where it seems Fedora 24 install comes with a newer version, thus causing the issue.  This can be seen by running `gradle --debug` and seeing the following output:

```
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices] Unable to load from native-platform backed Consol
eDetector. Continuing with fallback. Failure: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Failed to load native library 'libnative-pl
atform-curses.so' for Linux amd64.
caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/dkowis/.gradle/native/19/linux-amd64/libnative-platform-curses.so: libncurses.so.5: c
annot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The temporary solution is to create a symbolic link to the new libncurses.so.6 library as follows:

> sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.6 /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5

After doing this, Gradle now outputs the build status text as it did previously.

Comment: There is some indication on the gradle-dev mailing list that this may (at least in part) be due to a library they use called Jansi.  Stayed tuned!